# Invalid session token in Parse, after changing password

Tags: parse-platform

I'm making an app which in a user can change his password.
After logging in everything works perfect, but after opening the "Profile" activity and setting the password, when I go back to other activities which use ParseUser queries, I get an "Invalid session token" error. 
It happens only after saving the new password (With ParseUser.LogInBackgroud...).
How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Check the settings of your app and see if the setting for "Revoke existing session tokens when user changes password". If it is turned on, the system works as expected and you should turn it off https://monosnap.com/file/HobLyDmHrdNbKVpTFlM3Knl0SwDNLG

Comment: After changing password re-login current user, your session will be refreshed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modifying the password will *by default* delete all of that user's sessions. At that time, you need to have the user log in again in order to create a new session. See your app's settings on Parse under User Sessions.